# If A is not invertible, then Ax=b has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have seen in my textbook that If $A$ is not invertible, then $Ax=b$ has no solution, where $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and $b$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
But there was no proof.
In order to understand this I am searching for a proof.
I know that since A is not invertible then $det(A)=0$, that means that columns of $A$ are LD

Comment: That's false. Consider $A=0$ and $b=0$: there are infinitely many solutions. What's true is that *if the system $Ax=b$ has solutions and $A$ is not invertible, then the system has infinitely many solutions*.

Comment: Obviously there are some instances in which $Ax=b$.  Take any $x$ and compute $b$ accordingly.  Presumably your text meant that the equation is not solvable for all $b$.

Comment: @lulu for example what kind of x and b?

Comment: That would depend on $A$. E.g. if $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$, then $Ax=\left(\begin{matrix}m\\n\end{matrix}\right)$ has no solutions for any $m\ne n$.

Comment: Better to say: If square matrix $A$ is not invertible, then there exists $b$ so that $Ax=b$ has no solution.  Not invertible means not surjective, so anything outside the image of $A$ is such a $b$.

Comment: If, say, $A$ were an $n\times n$ square matrix then let $x$ be any $n-$vector.

Comment: Take the matrix $A$ and a vector $a$, and set $b=Aa$ - then the equation $Ax=b$ has at least the solution $x=a$

Answer (score 3):

No, the conclusion you should make is that you can't *guarantee* a solution. For example, one should think of $A:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ as a linear map with a kernel. In the case where this is injective, the map is invertible, so we can always find a solution $x= A^{-1}b$.

On the other hand, if $b$ is some vector, it might be in the *image* of $A$, which is to say that there exists some $x$ so that $Ax=b$ (this is more or less tautological.) There might be different choices of $x$ (noninjectivity) in which case we can't just take an inverse, but there will be a solution.

An easy example is the map $\mathbb R^2$ that projects onto the $x$-axis, as in  $A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$, which is not invertible. If $b=(a,0)$, there are solutions, and indeed many of them, namely $A(a,b)=a$ for all $b \in \mathbb R$. Otherwise, take $(a,b)$, ,with $b \neq 0$. Clearly there is no solution here.

Comment: @JohnDoe thanks.